# Acces log in Wildfly clustered environment

Tags: logging, wildfly-10

I enabled acces logging in Wildfly clustered environment on the nodes using their profile with the help of [this description](https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Undertow_WildFly_Subsystem_Configuration_-_access-log), but it doesn't provide me any information regarding the IP of the requestor, because the IP is always the IP of the master server.

Is it possible to extract the IP of the machine, from where the request came?

Answer (score 1):

Add `%{i,X-Forwarded-For}` as part of your log statement.  This is a standard HTTP header (originally from [Apache mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers)) that should be added to each request.

Comment: I added it to the log pattern, and added `proxy-address-forwarding="true"` to the http listener, but `X-Forwarded-For` was not added to the request parameters. If I add it to the request manually, then I see it in the log, but a normal request doesn't contain it. What can be the problem?